# What do I do when inptr == NULL?

Tags: c

I'm taking an introductory computer science course. We've been taught to check if inptr is NULL whenever we open a file with the code below:

```
//open dictionary
FILE* inptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");
if (inptr == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open dictionary.\n");
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that we haven't been taught what to do about it. So when I run my code, it's printing the error message and returning false. What do I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

to fix the problem, figure out and then provide a valid path to some file in the parameter you've named "`dictionary`"

e.g., how about trying to open "`/etc/groups`" (assuming you're running on a UNIX machine).

or, to be more precise:

```
 FILE* inptr = fopen("/etc/groups", "r");
```

or

```
 char * pathToFile = "/etc/groups";
 FILE * inptr = fopen(pathToFile, "r");
```

EDITED to add:

since you say "`dictionary`" is a variable that points to the path, print it out and then see if you can "cd" to the folder / directory that contains it.

e.g.:

```
 printf( "path to my dictionary is %s", dictionary );
 FILE * inptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");
```

Comment: so fopen(/dict.txt, "r")? Also I can't hard code the dictionary. It's a variable.

Comment: "`fopen(/dict.txt)`" will fail because a hard coded path needs to be within quotes, or a variable.  If the path is simply "`/dict.txt`", see if there is a "`dict.txt`" file on the root of your hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

To narrow down the error , always perror() to interpret the error code returned by the operating system.

```
 FILE* inptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");
     if (inptr == NULL)
     {
         perror("Could not open dictionary.\n");
         return false;
     }
```

Comment: Right.  And one could have the program look at `errno` (which `perror` references) to see if the cause of the error is something the program can do something about, or at least produce a more useful error message.

Answer (score 0):

If your program file and "dictionary" file are in the same directory then you do not need to give path , else you have to give complete path of you file name.

```
For e.g:- if your "dictionary" file is in /home/user_name/Documents then 
          FILE* inptr = fopen("/home/user_name/Documents/dictionary", "r");
```

Also include file name under quotes("/home/user_name/Documents/dictionary")

For more info this will help you

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Answer (score 0):

Changes the error message to:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Could not open dictionary file '%s'.\n", dictionary);
```

So that it is more informative.

Upon receipt of this error you change a) check that the variable `dicationary` is what you are expecting and b) If so check using the shell that you can access it (file ownership/file permissions etc).

Answer (score 0):

There's no "one true answer" as to what to do in this case. It really depends on your context and on your design. It depends of what your program is and how it is supposed to work. There's no way to answer your question without knowing more.

For example, if your program is interactive and if the file name you passed to `fopen` was interactively entered by the user, then a viable course of action would be to tell user that the file could not be opened and ask them to re-enter the file name.

If your program is some sort of "batch processing" program that takes its parameters from some sort of user-supplier config file, the a viable approach would be to terminate the program immediately with a meaningful error message, i.e. ask the user to edit the config file an re-run the program.

If your program, is some sort of server program that is supposed to be always running, then you might decide to log the error and continue working as best as you can without that file.

Of course, it all might also depends on how critical that file is to your program's operation. If this file is absolutely necessary, the you have to either terminate with a fatal error or keep cycling asking the user for proper file name.

If the file is optional, you might issue a warning about missing file and continue working assuming some default configurations and/or convention (that would otherwise be overridden by the missing file).

The above are just some generic considerations. There's no way to say anything more concrete without knowing more about your program, the missing file and the role it plays.